# Summarizing one column by the uniq names of places in second column in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to summarize column 1 (amount of money spent) by the unique places in column 2. I have been using the code:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' q5.txt
```

But it only sums it up by the unique first word of the second column which is a lot less than if it was unique to all of the words in the second column.

Data:

- 1380.54 Trump Hotel NY
- 9583.33 Trump Tower Commercial LLC
- 37993.04 The Trump Corporation
- 396.06 Trump Hotel NY
- ...

without bullet points having hard time formating

Output of code:

- Other 58464.3
- Trump 4.15534e+06
- The 231601

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[substr($0,index($0,FS)+1)]+=$1}; END { for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' myFile
```